# How to share information between .NET programs

Tags: asp.net, .net, ipc

I´m working on .NET web application that also runs different jobs at the background. These background jobs update the database, create report files, delete old files etc.

The jobs are triggered on a schedule and the scheduler itself is triggered every hour via Windows´ task scheduler.

So far I´ve been monitoring the status of the jobs by logging messages to windows events viewer however this method is very cumbersome.
I'd like to implement a new program with a GUI that will communicate with the jobs and monitor their activities. For start the gui should display the following information:

- Status (run vs idle)
- Progress bar ("24% done", "327 of 23423 items are finished")

The gui.exe should run independently from the jobs.exe (Starting or stopping the gui should not influence the jobs and vice versa).

I'm looking for advices, what is the best way to share information between jobs.exe and gui.exe

Comment: "what is the best way to share information" there are lots of ways: which is better (I doubt any will be singularly "best") for a particular use will depend on the details. Personally I would look at WMI because it would enable remote and command line (automated) monitoring. Also would look to expose performance counters.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the OS's mechanisms - performance counters, Windows events, etc. They are already supported by .NET. There are a *lot* of tools (GUI and otherwise) that use them for dashboarding, alerting, monitoring etc

Answer (score 0):

General answer - all forms of IPC involve using some shared resource accessible by both processes. Examples:

- network sockets (with "network" as shared resource)
- named pipes
- shared memory
- plain old disk files (not the best way to do IPC but still a valid one)
- a shared database

Specific .NET options:

- Remoting
- WCF
- Web API
- named pipes

to name a few.

Research some of them and see if they fit your usecase

Comment: Note the OP is actually asking about *monitoring* an application, but assumed IPC is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether the gui.exe will be running on the same system as your job services. If so then better not use any web api / network sockets / WCF for communication, but something rather more simple as IPC method. I personally like message queues.